Set service Startup Type to "Automatic (DelayedStart)" with PowerShell
I'm trying to script changing specific services to have Startup Type "Automatic (DelayedStart)". When I pipe the services into Set-CimInstance, I get an error that it "could not modify readonly property 'StartMode'". When I pipe it into Invoke-CimMethod, the script runs without error (and ReturnValue 21) but nothing actually changes. What am I doing wrong, and where do I get a list of return values?
ForEach ($Server in $Servers) {
    $Services = @("MSSQL", "MSSQLSERVER", "SQLAgent")

    $Before = @()
    ForEach ($Service in $Services) {
        $Before += Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $Server -ClassName 'Win32_Service' -Property * | Where-Object -Property Name -like "*$Service*"
        }

    $Before | Format-Table -Property PSComputerName, Name, StartMode, DelayedAutoStart, State, StartName -AutoSize

    ForEach ($Item in $Before.Name) {
        Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Service -ComputerName $Server -Filter "Name = '$($Item)'" | Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName Change -Arguments @{StartMode = "AutomaticDelayedStart"}
        # Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Service -ComputerName $Server -Filter "Name = '$($Item)'" | Set-CimInstance -Property @{StartMode = "AutomaticDelayedStart"}
        ### Error is: Set-CimInstance : Could not modify readonly property 'StartMode' of object 'Win32_Service: <Caption> <Name>
        }

    $After = @()
    ForEach ($Service in $Services) {
        $After += Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $Server -ClassName 'Win32_Service' -Property * | Where-Object -Property Name -like "*$Service*"
        }

    $After | Format-Table -Property PSComputerName, Name, StartMode, DelayedAutoStart, State, StartName -AutoSize
    }

